# Is there a default Pandas method for removing null or missing values when they are represented by a custom value like "?" or "Unknown"

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataset I'm working on, the [Adult dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult), the missing values are indicated with the `"?"` string, and I want to discard the rows containing missing values.

In the documentation of the method `df.dropna()` there is no argument that offers the possibility of passing a custom value to interpret as the null/missing value,

I know I can simply solve the problem with something like:

```py
df_str = df.select_dtypes(['object']) # get the columns containing the strings
for col in df_str.columns:
    df = df[df[col] != '?']
```

but I was wondering if there is a standard way of achieving this **using Pandas apis** which possibly offers more flexibility all while being faster.

Comment: if you're importing the data with `read_csv` for example  (I don't know the source format), you could use the `na_values` parameter to define additional strings to recognise as NA/NaN.

Comment: @DocZerø your comment is the closest to the solution I was looking for, if you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're importing the data from CSV for example, you could use the parameter `na_values` to define additional strings to recognise as NA/NaN.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = \
"""
A;B;C
1;2;?
4;?;6
?;8;9
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),
                 delimiter=';', 
                 na_values='?')
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | 6 |
| NaN | 8 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do `any`, this is to check row not contain `?`: if match it will return `True`, the `~` will turn that to `False` and filter

```
df = df[~df_str.eq('?').any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `replace` it with NaN and `dropna`:

```
df = df.replace('?', float('nan')).dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace('?', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

followed by `.dropna()`